# React-Router ^2.4.0 ERROR. Relatives routes don't find elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

it is my firs ask here, in Stack OverFlow. I am working with React and React-Router but I have the next error on Chrome:

`GET http://localhost:3000/alumno/src/fonts/awesome/css/font-awesome.css`

The route is: `http://localhost:3000/alumno/inicio`

If the route would be: `http://localhost:3000/inicio` ; I will not have any problem, all sources loads correctly, the problem appear when I have more than one children after localhost (`http://localhost:3000/XXX/YYY`). My structure of files is: Folder_PUBLIC > ( Index.html; Index.js Folder_SRC > ( all my srcs ) ). I am seeing that always tries to load the sources from last child. So this folder does not exists. It may load the sources from the root / as I have defined on my Index.html. I show you my files:

INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="./src/images/icono.ico"/>
    <title>Universidad Politécnica de Cartagena</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./src/fonts/awesome/css/font-awesome.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./src/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./src/css/select2.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./src/css/index.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="idRoot" class="container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/js/select2.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

WEBPACK.CONFIF.JS

```
'use strict';
var CopyFiles = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
},
context: __dirname,
entry: {
    app: ['./src/index.jsx']
},
output: {
    path: './public',
    filename: 'index.js'
    /*,
    publicPath: '/'
    */
},
devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    inline: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /(\.js|.jsx)$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                "presets": [
                    "es2015",
                    "react",
                    "stage-0"
                ],
                "plugins": [
                    "react-html-attrs",
                    "transform-decorators-legacy",
                    "transform-class-properties"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css?$/,
            loaders: [
                'style',
                'css'
            ]
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new CopyFiles([
        { 
            from: './src/index.html',
            to: './' 
        },
        { 
            from: './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
            to: './src/js' 
        },
        { 
            from: './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            to: './src/js' 
        },
        { 
            from: './node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.js',
            to: './src/js' 
        },
        { 
            from: './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css', 
            to: './src/css' 
        },
        { 
            from: './node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.css',
            to: './src/css' 
        },
        { 
            from: './src/styles/index.css', 
            to: './src/css' 
        },
        {
            context: './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts',
            from: '**/*',
            to: './src/fonts'
        },
        {
            context: './src/fonts',
            from: '**/*',
            to: './src/fonts'
        },
        {
            context: './src/images',
            from: '**/*',
            to: './src/images'
        }
    ])
]
```

}

My Bootstrap, jQuery,... is pure, I do not import it on React and I do not use React-Bootstrap, etc.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links to your static resources (CSS and JS) are all relative to the current page's URL. Fix it by making the URLs absolute – simply remove the dot at the beginning:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/src/fonts/awesome/css/font-awesome.css"/>
```